# Rewriting $|\Psi\rangle=\sum_n c_n |\Phi_n\rangle$ into $|\Phi_n\rangle$ as a function of $c_n$ and $|\Psi\rangle$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, fourier-transform, linear-algebra

Given that $\{|\Phi_n\rangle\}$ is an orthonormal basis, how can I express $|\Phi_n\rangle$ in $c_n$ and $|\Psi\rangle$?
\begin{equation}
|\Psi\rangle=\sum_n c_n |\Phi_n\rangle
\end{equation}

Comment: It's not really clear how your question is related to a Fourier transform exactly. Is it a quantum Fourier transform?  Or are you asking how to compute the $c_n$'s for a general orthonormal basis? Then do the normal thing of taking the inner product of the vector with the members of the orthonormal basis.

Comment: I know how to compute the $c_n$s for an orthonormal basis, however, I was wondering if i can do the inverse if I know the coefficients $c_n$ and the resulting wavefunction $\Psi$.  Can I construct an expression for $\Phi$ in those terms? Maybe I should rephrase my question. In Griffiths this is refered to as Fouriers trick.

Comment: Consider to use \langle and \rangle instead of < and >.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick one term out of the sum on the RHS, say $n=1$, and write it as $|\Phi_1 \rangle = c_1^{-1} ( |\Phi \rangle - \sum_{n\neq 1} c_n | \Phi_n \rangle )$, assuming $c_1 \neq 0$. Now we have $\Phi_1$ in the form you requested. For the rest, $\Phi_n$ with $n=2,3,\dots$, they are independent of $c_n$ and $|\Phi \rangle$ in this representation.

If you want something that looks more like a Fourier transform, you need to give a complete set of states rather than just one state $\Phi$.